# Passing data between two seperate Yii web applications

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, rest, yii

I have a yii application **(APP1)**, and a separate yii application **(APP2)** that I would like to download multiple rows/tables from **APP1** to **APP2**, complete some actions and then send them back to **APP1** (whilst completing the tasks **APP2** may be offline).

Currently I have a request (using `GET`) that gives me all the data I need in a `json` object from **APP1**.

I am not too sure how best to proceed from here? Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this?

```
  public function actionDownload($id) {
    // Check if id was submitted via GET
    if(!isset($_GET['id']))
        $this->_sendResponse(500, 'Error: Parameter <b>id</b> is missing' );
        $model = AuditLines::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>'line_audit_id='.$_GET['id']));

    if(is_null($model))
        $this->_sendResponse(404, 'No Items found with id '.$_GET['id']);
    else
        $this->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($model));
    }
```

That gets me all the data I need, now I need to place that data into temporary tables in APP2's database, then I can modify send back once complete

** Update **
Another issue here will be that APP1 will be on a live server, and APP2 will be hosted on a WAMP server. APP2 will need to get the data (tables/rows) from APP1 and then go offline whilst the work is completed. Once the job is finished(and APP2 has an internet connection) it will need to pass the data back to APP1 to be processed
Thanks for all your help

Comment: and what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a webservice
**I am showing you how to do it using soap.**
 
In your **App1**

```
class WebServicesForUserController extends Controller
{
public function actions()
    {
        return array(
        // 'services' will be used in app2 while making soap object
            'services'=>array(
                'class'=>  'CWebServiceAction',

            )
        );
    }
/**
 *@return mixed
 *@soap
 */
public function sendData()
{
// do all your processing here and store data in a variable 
$variable=array('my data');
// then just return the data in the json form
return json_encode($variable);
}
}
```

In **APP2** you can call this webservice to get data like

```
class GetMyServiceController extends CController
{

public function actionMyData()
{
// create a soap object
$wsdl='http://path/to/your/app1/function/services';
            $client=new SoapClient($wsdl);
            $result=$client->sendData();
           echo $result
}

}
```

**For more details click** [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.webservice)

Comment: Thanks,I didnt know that Yii had web services built in, the data I will receive  will be a model with multiple rows, is there an easy way to just directly import these to a database using Yii in APP2 ?

Answer (score 0):

you can open multiple database connection to different databases in 1 app

```
'components' => array(
    'db' => array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=dbserver1;dbname=my1db',
        ...
    ),
    'dbadvert' => array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=adserver2;dbname=advertisingDB',
        'username'         => 'advertuser',
        'password'         => '***********',
        ...
        'class'            => 'CDbConnection'          // DO NOT FORGET THIS!
    ),
```

source: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/#hh0

besides that if both apps are hosted on the same server app1 can load controllers/models/helpers from another physical location then from within the protected path.

Comment: That's a very interesting point, and these sort of things are exactly why I asked the question, to get different ideas on how to solve the problem. I did forget to mention that APP1 will be on a live server, and APP2 will be on a WAMP server with a view to downloading tables/rows and then going offline. Thanks for the input !

Comment: what if you mount your live app folder as a shared network drive on your windows local machine ? and if it is for a datapull i would not make a live app load/execute code for a local app. the live app will need to do more work and people actually visiting your live app will suffer under it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the folder thing? the live site (APP1) will be on a linux server, and local app (APP2) will be on a windows laptop using wamp, resources are not an issue on the live server. Its not just a data pull I need the data to be downloaded, modified offline via user input and then sent back for verification.

Comment: imho the best thing to do then would be accessing the live db directly from the local app and do the verification locally as well, but that doesn't mean you can't reuse the code (for example share the duplicate code in a separate git repo and have them in both projects as submodules)